# Bundler difference between setup and require?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I often see 2 variations in projects that use Bundler.

One is:

```
require "bundler/setup"
Bundler.require(:default)
```

And another:

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup :default, (ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development')
```

Are tye both the same or have variations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google can be your friend. Read [this](http://anti-pattern.com/bundler-setup-vs-bundler-require) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922475/whats-the-difference-between-bundle-setup-and-bundle-require).

> TL;DR Use Bundler.require instead of Bundler.setup

Answer (score 1):

`Bundler.setup` prepares the load paths to the specific gems in your `Gemfile.lock` so that you can then require each gem on an as-needed basis. `Bundler.require` further goes through each of the gems and requires each gem (by requiring the file for which the gem is named, if it exists).

You can read the implementation for yourself in [`bundler.rb`](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler.rb) and [`runtime.rb`](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/runtime.rb).